Old science fiction book in which an American travels to another planet to prevent communists from corrupting the primitive inhabitants
Trying to find an old science fiction book I never finished reading as a kid. It was mid 90's when I picked it up, it was from my dad's old book collection so I don't know exactly how much older it was.
I remember the book was kinda old, as it had an American travel to another planet to prevent the communists from corrupting the primitive inhabitants which were pretty human. The key detail I can remember is the man made a very durable knife out of some sort of crystal to prevent the inhabitants of learning about his technology.
I never got far into the book and I seem to remember the cover having a guy fighting an animal with a knife in a jungle setting, but I could be mixing the cover memory up with a different book cover.

In roughly which year did you read this?

It was in the mid 90's when I picked it up , it was from my dad's old book collection so I don't know exactly how old it was.

Based on the subject matter, I would think it was probably published in the 50s or 60s. Yes, the cold war lasted until the 1991, but I think sci-fi shifted away from stories about America vs communism in the 70s. (But that's just my opinion based of recollection. I could be wrong.)

Turtledove's A World of Difference (1990) features Americans vs. Commies on a planet with intelligent low-tech natives, but doesn't have the cover you describe.

.I think it was from the 50's as I recall it was mixed in the bookshelf with a few Isaac Asimov books. A World of difference seems like a nice read but recall it was america vs communists they didn't work together in the book at all.

Bears some resemblance to Andre Norton's The Defiant Agents - modern day Apache sent to an uninhabited planet as "traditional" Apache to prevent the communists taking over that planet and gaining access to alien tech. Features aliens, very much not primitive; long-absent IIRC.

I'm going to buy the defiant agents  from Amazon and see if that's the correct book thanks for posting bob1
